# Вывести запросить цену

Tags: php, битрикс

есть проблема, если цена пустая, есть кнопка цена по запросу. А если цена 0, надпись подписаться. Помогите сделать, что и при 0 цене и при пустой была надпись Запросить цену. Ниже кусок кода.
Этот addCart changeID changeQty changeCart disabled requestPrice класс отвечает за вывод надписи цена по запросу

```
        <?if(!empty($arResult["PRICE"])):?>
            <?if($arResult["CATALOG_AVAILABLE"] != "Y"):?>
                <?if($arResult["CATALOG_SUBSCRIBE"] == "Y"):?>
                    <a href="#" class="addCart subscribe changeID changeQty changeCart" data-id="<?=$arResult["ID"]?>" data-quantity="<?=$arResult["EXTRA_SETTINGS"]["BASKET_STEP"]?>"><span><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/subscribe.png" alt="<?=GetMessage("SUBSCRIBE_LABEL")?>" class="icon"><?=GetMessage("SUBSCRIBE_LABEL")?></span></a>
                <?else:?>
                    <a href="#" class="addCart changeID changeQty changeCart disabled" data-id="<?=$arResult["ID"]?>" data-quantity="<?=$arResult["EXTRA_SETTINGS"]["BASKET_STEP"]?>"><span><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/incart.png" alt="<?=GetMessage("ADDCART_LABEL")?>" class="icon"><?=GetMessage("ADDCART_LABEL")?></span></a>
                <?endif;?>
            <?else:?>
                <a href="#" class="addCart changeID changeQty changeCart" data-id="<?=$arResult["ID"]?>" data-quantity="<?=$arResult["EXTRA_SETTINGS"]["BASKET_STEP"]?>"><span><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/incart.png" alt="<?=GetMessage("ADDCART_LABEL")?>" class="icon"><?=GetMessage("ADDCART_LABEL")?></span></a>
            <?endif;?>
        <?else:?>
            <a href="#" class="addCart changeID changeQty changeCart disabled requestPrice" data-id="<?=$arResult["ID"]?>" data-quantity="<?=$arResult["EXTRA_SETTINGS"]["BASKET_STEP"]?>"><span><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/request.png" alt="<?=GetMessage("REQUEST_PRICE_BUTTON_LABEL")?>" class="icon"><?=GetMessage("REQUEST_PRICE_BUTTON_LABEL")?></span></a>
        <?endif;?>
```

Comment: `.. || $arResult["PRICE"] == 0` ?

Comment: Тогда даже если в наличии, пишет запросить цену

Comment: Пардон, `.. &&  $arResult["PRICE"] != 0`. Тогда будет: Если не пусто и не равно нулю, тогда .. иначе показать цену. Сплю сижу..и туплю на пару )

Comment: так?
<?if(!empty($arResult["PRICE"] &&  $arResult["PRICE"] != 0)):?>

Comment: `<?if(!empty($arResult["PRICE"]) && $arResult["PRICE"] != 0):?>`

Comment: не работает (((((((

Comment: Что у вас в `$arResult["PRICE"]` находится, выведите

Comment: там просто цена формата 0.00

Comment: Тогда условие, что выше - рабочее. В том случае, если передан 0.00 ваш, то будет просить цену. Если передано, например, 0.01, то условие пройдет

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/PQTsbM2.png

Comment: А вы уверены, что 0.00 это не placeholder ? Сделайте, например, var_dump переменной и посмотрите, что в ней..

Comment: в админке 
<input type="text" id="CAT_BASE_PRICE" name="CAT_BASE_PRICE" value="0.00" size="30">

Comment: Вы когда кнопочку нажимаете типа "Отправить", данные уходят в обработчик. Вот там и ловите их, смотрите, что по итогу пришло. Если конкретнее, то в том скрипте, фрагмент кода которого вы привели в вопросе. Условие я проверил, оно выполняется.  Какие данные там по итогу приходят - не могу знать 

Можете вообще написать что-то вроде
`if ($arResult["PRICE"] > 0) ... else ..` и условие будет работать нормально, без всяких `!empty`. Т.к. `"0.00" > 0 = false, 0.00 > 0 = false, -0.01 > 0 = false, "" > 0 = false, 0.01 > 0 = true`